# Resolving patch conflicts manually

Tags: vim, vi, patch

I've downloaded a patch from some site and trying to apply it (`twisted`, python web framework).

Several hunks failed.

How do I automate manual patching process using vim?

**Details:**

I'm trying to automate the process of applying failed hunks.

Many tiny changes, each about adding/removing 1-2 chars. Difficult to see.

I Have to create two new temporary files and `:diffthis` them manually to see the difference. Yes, outside VCS. 
I can imagine a neat way to deal with it using git, but I would prefer to avoid creating git repo for that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by automating a manual process?

Comment: I'm missing something here.  What are you trying to automate in particular?  The process of applying a patch?  The process of reconciling a patch that doesn't quite work?

Comment: I guess you're totally outside VCS, and just want to get the failed hunks pasted into the file around the right place so you can see them and do it yourself?

Comment: Answered in `Details` section above.